# I'm trying to use Javascript to display an image

Tags: javascript, image, html-table

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game. I'm using images instead of Xs and Os, so I need to fill in a td with an image when it is clicked on. I tried this:

```
function makeDuck(place){
    //this is just so I know the other methods work
    alert("duck");            
    //This is the line I need help with 
    window.location.write('<img src="smallDuck.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>'); 
    squares[place] = 1;
}

function makeBeaver(place){
    //this is just so I know the other methods work
    alert("beaver"); 
    //This is the line I need help with           
    document.zero.write('<img src="smallBeaver.jpg" width="80" height="80"/>');
    squares[place] = 2;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to learn about attributes and DOM manipulations and just more JavaScript in general. `.write` can't be used in that way at all.

Comment: I agree, with @minitech kudos for jumping in head first though.  I learn best from trying stuff just like this, than someone comes along and shows me how to do it 10x easier

Comment: You might want to take a look at JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), its a great, lightweight way of quickly protyping/testing bits of JavaScript and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function makeDuck(place){
    // first, we must create a new element in the DOM
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    // second, we must assign the right attributes
    img.src = "smallDuck.jpg";
    img.width = "70";
    img.height = "70";

    // finally, we append it to the document
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    squares[place] = 1;
}

function makeBeaver(place){
    // first, we must create a new element in the DOM
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    // second, we must assign the right attributes
    img.src = "smallBeaver.jpg";
    img.width = "80";
    img.height = "80";

    // finally, we append it to the document
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    squares[place] = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to use javascript to replace the source of an `IMG`. So supposing you have a 3 x 3 grid, each cell contains an `<img />` tag. They'll all need unique `id`s.

And you'll have 3 images: blank.jpg, X.jpg and Y.jpg. All cells start off with
`<img src='blank.jpg' ... />`

Use Javascript to locate the element (getDocumentById(id)) and set its `src` property to the URI set as the `src` of the X or Y images .

Comment: I've built a little demo for you. It uses JQuery (which in turn calls native Javascript functions like `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` and so on. It might help you get your head around the concepts. http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/5sXRd/

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you going, first the styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
table.game {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.game td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
td.topLeft, td.topCenter, td.midLeft, td.midCenter {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td.topRight, td.midRight {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td.botLeft, td.botCenter {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.botRight { }

.naught {
  background-image: url('naught.jpg');
}
.cross {
  background-image: url('cross.png');
}

</style>
```

Then the HTML for the game

```
<table class="game" onclick="handleClick(event);">
  <tr>
    <td class="topLeft">
    <td class="topCenter">
    <td class="topRight">
  <tr>
    <td class="midLeft">
    <td class="midCenter">
    <td class="midRight">
  <tr>
    <td class="botLeft">
    <td class="botCenter">
    <td class="botRight">
</table>
```

Then a simple script to swap images:

```
<script>
var handleClick = (function() {
    var count = 0;

    return function(evt) {
      var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
      el.className += ' ' + (count++%2? 'naught' : 'cross');
    }
}());
</script>
```

Note that you should deal with multiple clicks on the same cell (check to see if the class already has a value of 'naught' or 'cross' and if it does, tell the user to click elsewhere) and give a hint whose turn it is.